# How to pass a function to child component as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to pass down a function `isLoggedIn` to child component `HandleArticle` as a prop.
Even though I am using arrow function due to `this` issue, `TypeError: this.isLoggedIn is not a function` occurs.

```
class HandleNews extends React.Component {
  isLoggedIn = () => {
    if (!this.props.isSignedIn) {
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      return <div>hello</div>;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to="/news/article">
          <HandleArticle isLoggedIn={this.isLoggedIn} />
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HandleNews);
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. The code is workable. The only place where you refer `this.isLoggedIn` is `render`, it won't result in `TypeError: this.isLoggedIn is not a function` error. What's HandleArticle?

Comment: code looks alright, maybe your babel doesn't supports arrow functions, check your webpack and babel config. If you are using CRA then it should work automatically.

Comment: I think you have to bind the isloggedin function in the constructor of the HandleNews component

Comment: It's weird. I changed the name of the function and it starts to work. Probably it was a syntax error I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal), the arrow syntax is still in proposal stage for passing functions.

```
isLoggedIn = () => {
    if (!this.props.isSignedIn) {
      history.push("/");
    } else {
      return <div>hello</div>;
    }
  };
```

Use **bind** syntax in **constructor** for isLoggedIn function

```
this.isLoggedIn = this.isLoggedIn .bind(this);
```

**Bind** directly in **render** function

```
<HandleArticle isLoggedIn={this.isLoggedIn.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: Did not know that arrow syntax is still in proposal stage.
Thank you it works :)